# Round a number after a calculation with 'Math.round'

Tags: javascript, rounding

I can't get `Math.round(num * 100) / 100` to work. I am using normal jQuery and I don't get it.

This script converts a length and works perfectly:

```html
<script>
  var meters = document.getElementsByClassName("num");
  for (var i = 0; i < meters.length; i++) {
    meters[i].innerHTML = parseInt(meters[i].innerHTML) * 3.2808399;
  }
</script>

<p class="num">12</p>
<p class="num">7</p>
```

Comment: show where you are using Math.round - it's not in the code snippet you provided! jQuery is a library written in javascript that has nothing at all to do with javascript Math.round - so, not sure why you even mentioned it

Comment: yes, i don't know where i can use it - that's why i ask

Comment: Also nothing in the posted code has anything to do with jQuery.

Comment: I normally use jQuery so i don't know how i can do this with java script

Comment: jQuery **is** JavaScript.

Comment: any idea to solve the problem?

Comment: What problem?  You have not explained what you want to achieve, what you have tried (involving `Math.round()`), what's going wrong or what's confusing you, or what you don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

Something like that???? 
I am not sure what you are trying to do....

```js
var meters = document.getElementsByClassName("num");
for (var i = 0; i < meters.length; i++) {
  meters[i].innerHTML = Math.round(parseInt(meters[i].innerHTML) * 3.2808399 * 100) / 100
}
```

```html
<p class="num">12</p>
<p class="num">7</p>
```

Comment: Thanks! This helps a lot